# Rails 3 - How to query on a polymorphic belongs_to association with squeel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, squeel

I am using [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) for my questions/answers application.
Each question and each answer can be voted (à la stack overflow).

I am using [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) and looking for a way to get the following : order the questions from the most voted to the less voted ; and for each question, order the answers from the most voted to the less voted.

What should be the best [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) query for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this type of query is to use the cache system described in the main page of [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) and then perform this request : `Question.order("cached_votes_up desc")`

Answer (score 0):

You can do polymorphic belongs to like as follows

```
Note.joins{notable(Person).outer}
```